# How to parse or use large data locally inside flutter. i am creating a quran app which is having a large data

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a Quran App which is having large data. I added all the data as in json format in the assets.
But decoding it for some chapters taking so much time.

Any best method for optimizing the app.
Below are the codes.

```
  Future<String> getJson() {
    return rootBundle.loadString('assets/text_asset/quranex.json');
  }

  List<QuranAyah> data;

  List<QuranAyah> quranAyahFromJson(String str) =>
      List<QuranAyah>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => QuranAyah.fromJson(x)));

  Future getData() async {
    data = quranAyahFromJson(await getJson());
    print(data[0].aya);

    return data;
  }
```

below is the widget

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: getData(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: data[widget.index].aya.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return AutoScrollTag(
                          key: ValueKey(index),
                          highlightColor: Colors.green.shade100,
                          controller: controller,
                          index: index,
                          child: AyahWidget(
                            surahMeaning: widget.titleMeaning,
                            surahName: widget.title,
                            surahIndex: widget.index + 1,
                            ayah: data[widget.index].aya[index].text,
                            index: data[widget.index].aya[index].index,
                            meaning: _thafseer
                                ? data[widget.index].aya[index].meaning
                                : "",
                            thafseer: _thafseer
                                ? data[widget.index].aya[index].thafseer
                                : "",
                          ),
                        );
                      })
                  : Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
            ),
```

the json modal is below

```
class QuranAyah {
  QuranAyah({
    this.index,
    this.name,
    this.surahmeaning,
    this.aya,
  });

  String index;
  String name;
  String surahmeaning;

  List<Aya> aya;

  factory QuranAyah.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => QuranAyah(
        index: json["index"],
        name: json["name"],
        surahmeaning:
            json["surahmeaning"] == null ? null : json["surahmeaning"],
        aya: List<Aya>.from(json["aya"].map((x) => Aya.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "index": index,
        "name": name,
        "surahmeaning": surahmeaning == null ? null : surahmeaning,
        "aya": List<dynamic>.from(aya.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Aya {
  Aya({
    this.index,
    this.text,
    this.meaning,
    this.thafseer,
    this.vibagam,
    this.vajanam,
    this.bismillah,
  });

  String index;
  String text;
  String meaning;
  String thafseer;
  String vibagam;
  String vajanam;
  String bismillah;

  factory Aya.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Aya(
        index: json["index"],
        text: json["text"],
        meaning: json["meaning"] == null ? null : json["meaning"],
        thafseer: json["thafseer"] == null ? null : json["thafseer"],
        vibagam: json["vibagam"] == null ? null : json["vibagam"],
        vajanam: json["vajanam"] == null ? null : json["vajanam"],
        bismillah: json["bismillah"] == null ? null : json["bismillah"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "index": index,
        "text": text,
        "meaning": meaning == null ? null : meaning,
        "thafseer": thafseer == null ? null : thafseer,
        "vibagam": vibagam == null ? null : vibagam,
        "vajanam": vajanam == null ? null : vajanam,
        "bismillah": bismillah == null ? null : bismillah,
      };
}
```

and finaly the json data is here -> https://jsonblob.com/08cc5da3-4339-11eb-85e7-1b58be500f91

Comment: Where did  you get the quran data? Is it free?

Comment: yupp...i collected and merged from different sources

Comment: try to run some methods which are taking long time in `isolates`

Comment: And these sources have an explicit license that permits you to do what you're doing?  Also, I wouldn't store things in JSON (yuck).  Either use a key/value store (like Hive I keep hearing about), or sqflite.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz how could I store these data in the hive. when the app is totally offline. I am presetting the JSON data in assets.

Comment: json or any text type is better than storing using a DB as its a book. moreover its compile time data not runtime! @RandalSchwartz

Comment: split the data for smaller chunks/pages, load progressively, if there are 1000 pages, if the user is at 5th page, keep 4 and 6 page loaded, and others unloaded

Comment: @Yadu Did you looked at the json data...link shared!!!...what method do you prefer to do... i am using listview.builder...still the app is getting slow and using like 200+mb of memory usage.

Comment: make larger values of any key a separate file and value should be a reference to that file

Comment: any examples???

Comment: I found the solution..Actually the slowdown is not bcz of the json. it is the listview.Builder inside listview(). I tried removing lisview which is the parent of the listview builder